# Select a checkbox that selects other checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building out a simple user role management UI that has multiple permissions based on RBAC rules.
So I have lets say a group called users and inside of that group you get "add user", "edit users", "delete users" and "view users".

What I want to do is be able to select the entire "users" group checkbox and it should select the children checkboxes that belong to it, and so on. I have around 20 of these permissions groups.

I have looked around in stack overflow but am unable to find the solution or come up with something that works.

I'm looking for some help with either Javascript or Jquery.

I have included a screenshot to show you guys what I mean.

I don't have any JS code to show because I'm not even sure where to start.

I'm building the HTML view with `Blade` which is Laravel's templating engine. Here is my HTML so far.

```
@foreach($permissions as $name => $permission)
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
                {{ $name }}
            </label>
        </h4>
        @foreach($permission as $item)
            <div class="checkbox small">
                <label>
                        <input name="permissions[]" value="{{ $item }}" type="checkbox">
                    {{ $item }}
                </label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

[image: permissions]

Comment: Just give the parsed HTML. There is no need to limit the people you can answer this to those you know PHP using Blade. In fact giving us that makes this question more off-topic considering this is a *"give me the code"* type question in the first place.

Comment: As i understand you want when `users` check-box is checked to also check the child elements which are `add users`,`edit users`,`delete users`,`view users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add appropriate classes to your parent elements and to your child elements so your code could be altered like in the below example.

```
@foreach($permissions as $name => $permission)
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="{{ $name }}">
                {{ $name }}
            </label>
        </h4>
        @foreach($permission as $item)
            <div class="checkbox small">
                <label>
                        <input name="permissions[]" class="{{ $name }}-child" value="{{ $item }}" type="checkbox">
                    {{ $item }}
                </label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Your HTML will become like this regarding class names.

```
users<input class="users" type="checkbox" />
<br><br>
<input class="users-child" type="checkbox" />
<input class="users-child" type="checkbox" />
<input class="users-child" type="checkbox" />
<input class="users-child" type="checkbox" />
<input class="users-child" type="checkbox" />
<input class="users-child" type="checkbox" />
```

Finally your jQuery part

```
$(".users").on("click",function(){ // use the same code for user-roles
var parentClassName = $(this).get(0).className;
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("."+parentClassName+"-child").each(function(key,value){
    if($(value).get(0).checked==false) {
    $(value).get(0).checked = true;
    }
    });
} else {
    $("."+parentClassName+"-child").each(function(key,value){
    $(value).get(0).checked = false;
    });
}
});
```

A small example of the above you can check in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdwvoqtw/1/)

Comment: sorry to say I think there is a big problem in your code or it is not useless.
This code will only work if {{ $name }} always returns "users" and as I can see that this variable is inside the loop so in next iteration names value gets changed hence your script will not work.

Comment: @Vedant {{name}} inside the loop will get `users` as value and also `user-roles`.

Comment: so you mean you need to duplicate the same code. I don't think this is the way we should do it, right?

Comment: @Vedant if this website keeps good tracks on timing answers then one could see that i had start writing my answer before you add something. PS at the time i write sir i don't look what others write i focus on my answer, but to your good knowledge most of the times in my life it was the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

try code:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.col-sm-3 > h4 > label > input',function(){
         var tag = $(this).prop('checked');
         $(this).parents('.col-sm-3').find('.checkbox > label > input').prop('checked',tag);
    });
})
```

if code after render template:

```
 $(document).on('click','.col-sm-3 > h4 > label > input',func)
```

can replace with

```
$('.col-sm-3 > h4 > label > input').click(func)
```

Comment: Selectors are more bootstrap dependent which may change even next day if any change in design/size of the block... which I guess not a preferred way. (just saying.) because we need to change query on the basis of the change in col-md-3.

Comment: i am lazy, and poor english sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine but to make the answer even smaller I would like you to assign `class` attribute to your main div and checkbox so out jquery will depend on our own classes/selector instead of bootstrap classes.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 permission-block">
  <h4>
     <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="something">
           {{ $name }}
     </label>
  </h4>
```

and then your can add jQuery something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".something").on("click", function() {
      var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
      $(this).parent(".permission-block").children(".checkbox").find("input[type='checkbox']").props("checked", checked);
   })
})
```